# Maximal inequality of iid random variables $\{X_{ij}\}_{1\leqslant i,j \leqslant n}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, inequality, law-of-large-numbers

> Suppose that $\{X_{ij}\}_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}$ are iid random variables with $\mathbb{E}(X_{11})=0$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X_{11})=1$, does the following convergence hold:
> $$
> \max_{1\leqslant  j\leqslant n}\biggl\{\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{1\leqslant i\neq i'\leqslant n}(X_{ij}X_{i'j})\biggr\} \to 0 \qquad \text{almost surely}?
> $$

Comment: I have also posted this question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432114/maximal-inequality-of-iid-random-variables-x-ij-1-leqslant-i-j-leqslant) according to @D.R.'s suggestion.

### Background

I am reading the AoP paper "Limit of the smallest eigenvalue of a large dimensional sample covariance matrix" by Z. Bai and Y. Yin (1993). Their Lemma 2 states a generalization of the well-known Marcinkiewicz-Zygmund strong law of large numbers to the case of multiple arrays of iid random variables.

> [Lemma 2 in [Bai and Yin (1993)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-21/issue-3/Limit-of-the-Smallest-Eigenvalue-of-a-Large-Dimensional-Sample/10.1214/aop/1176989118.full) ] Let $\{\xi_{ij},i,j=1,2,\ldots\}$ be a double array of iid random variables and let $\alpha>1/2,\beta\geqslant 0$ and $M$>0 be constants. Then as $n\to\infty$,
> $$
> \max_{j\leqslant Mn^{\beta}} \biggl|n^{-\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n (\xi_{ij}-c)\biggr|\to0\quad \text{almost surely},
> $$
> if and only if
> $$
> (i)\quad \mathbb{E}|\xi_{11}|^{(1+\beta)/\alpha}<\infty
> $$
> $$
> (ii)\quad c =  \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
>       \mathbb{E} \,\xi_{11},& \text{if }\alpha\leqslant 1, \\
>       \text{any number}, &\text{if }\alpha>1.
> \end{array} 
> \right.  
> $$

By our assumptions and taking $\alpha=\beta=M=1$, $\xi_i=X_{ij}^2$ in this lemma, we have
$$
\max_{j\leqslant n}\biggl|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i,j}X_{ij}^2-1\biggr|\to0\quad \text{almost surely}.
$$
This result is for square terms. I wonder if there is a similar result for the **cross terms**
$$
\max_{1\leqslant  j\leqslant n}\biggl\{\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\neq i'}(X_{ij}X_{i'j})\biggr\} \to 0 \qquad \text{almost surely}?
$$

---

### Attempt

I can prove that $(1/n^2)\sum_{i\neq i'}(X_{ij}X_{i'j})\to 0\; a.s.$ for any fixed $j$. But I do not know how to deal with the problem with "$\max$".

For fixed $j$,
$$
\mathrm{Var}\Bigl(\sum_{i\neq i'}X_{ij}X_{i'j}\Bigr)=2\sum_{i\neq i'}\mathrm{E}\bigl(X_{ij}^2\bigr)\cdot\mathrm{E}\bigl(X_{i'j}^2\bigr)=2(n^2-n),
$$
then by Chebyshev's inequality, for any $\varepsilon>0$,
$$
\Pr\biggl(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\neq i'}(X_{ij}X_{i'j})>\varepsilon\biggr) =O\Bigl(\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigr),
$$
which is summable. Hence, by using the Borel-Cantelli lemma, we have
$$
\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\neq i'}(X_{ij}X_{i'j})\to 0\qquad
 \text{almost surely}.$$

If we consider $\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}$, and use the trivial inequality to bound it, we have
$$
\Pr\biggl(\max_{1\leqslant  j\leqslant n}\biggl\{\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\neq i'}(X_{ij}X_{i'j})\biggr\}> \varepsilon\biggr)
\leqslant n\cdot \Pr\biggl(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\neq i'}(X_{i1}X_{i'1})>\varepsilon\biggr)=O\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\Bigr),$$
which means
$$
\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}\biggl\{\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\neq i'}(X_{ij}X_{i'j})\biggr\}\to 0\qquad
 \text{in probability}.\tag{*}
$$

How can we improve the result (*) to "almost surely"?

Comment: Is there a book this is from?

Comment: @D.R. I have edited and added a question background for it.

Comment: so you your question is open question? If so, maybe post on Math Overflow instead

Comment: @D.R. Thanks for your kind suggestion! I post it on Math Overflow now. Should I delete the post here?

Comment: no, I think the best solution is cross posting (link each post in the other, with a comment explaining that you asked here first and then moved it over)

Comment: @D.R. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying
$$\tag{*}
\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant Mn^{\beta}} \biggl|n^{-\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n (\xi_{ij}-c)\biggr|\to0\quad \text{almost surely}
$$
to $\xi_{i,j}=X_{i,j}^2$, $M=1$, $\beta=1$ and $\alpha=2$ gives that
$$
\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant  n} \biggl|n^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_{i,j}^2-1\right)\biggr|\to0\quad \text{almost surely}
$$
which gives
$$
\tag{1}
\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant  n}  n^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,j}^2 \to0\quad \text{almost surely}.
$$
Applying (*) to $\xi_{i,j}=X_{i,j}$ (then $c=0$), $M=\alpha=\beta=1$ gives that
$$ 
\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant  n} \biggl|n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,j}\biggr|\to0\quad \text{almost surely}
$$
or in other words,
$$ \tag{2}
\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant  n}n^{-2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,j}\right)^2\to0\quad \text{almost surely}.
$$
The wanted convergence is the combination of (1) and (2).

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!